# How to use objective c libraries and swift frameworks in an objective c project?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have my project in objective c and all its pods are having libraries but now I want to install a new pod in it & when I install that pod it starts giving crash `library not loaded (image not found)`. When I change my podfile and uncomment the line `use_frameworks!` it will update all the pod libraries to the frameworks then it starts giving errors in other pods like `abc.h file not found`. How can I solve this issue ?

TIA

```
  source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
  pod 'GoogleMaps'
  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 3.0'
  pod 'FreeStreamer'
  pod 'iOS-Slide-Menu'
  pod 'XMLDictionary'
  pod 'HTMLReader'
  pod 'MarqueeLabel'
  pod 'pop'
  pod 'FBSDKCoreKit'
  pod 'FBSDKShareKit'
  pod 'FBSDKLoginKit'
  pod 'Google/SignIn'
  pod 'iCarousel'
  pod 'APParallaxHeader'
  pod 'CCBottomRefreshControl'
  pod 'GCPlaceholderTextView'
  pod 'VBFPopFlatButton'
  pod 'Firebase'
  pod 'Firebase/Crash'
  pod 'Firebase/Messaging'
  pod 'MBProgressHUD'
  pod 'VKVideoPlayer'
  pod 'LGPlusButtonsView'
  pod 'youtube-ios-player-helper'

  use_frameworks!
  pod 'SnapSDK'
```

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting use_frameworks! at the beginning of your pods specs ?
if that didn't work for you try deleting your derived data and rebuild

Comment: I have tried using use_frameworks! at the top of the pods and deleting the derived data and rebuilding the project, but the result is same it will change the libraries to frameworks which will gives errors in the pods. Any other work around ?